# Android: "Texting" List View?

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface

I need some help.

I'm wanting to make an activity similar to this, but I'm not sure where to start.

[image]

Basically, it's like a texting UI, with the users question on the right and the answer on the left. I was going to use a list view for the sake of simplicity, but I dont' think it'd support this kind of structure.

I googled some layouts where I can scroll, but most of them require me to premake them, which isnt an option because its a dynamic chat log.

Does anyone here have experience with this kind of UI? Can you point me in any direction? I hate to ask such a strange question, but I don't even know how I'd word this situation on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `ListView` where you can return a different layout depending on whether the message is sent or received. A `ListView` is the most efficient implementation for this because its ideal for displaying a potentially large data set without having to keep a view in memory for every row.

This is achieved by extending the `BaseAdapter` in your application and overriding the `getItemViewType()`, `getViewTypeCount()`, and `getView()` methods (along with all the other methods required by a `ListView` adapter).

[This](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) is a good tutorial that serves as a walkthrough for this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ListView, You may programmatically construct a viertical LinearLayout, and add TextView in each line, you can set the alignment of the TextView in lines accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide an example I can read? I'm fairly new to designing Android UIs. I don't know how to modify layouts while the software is running, only before.

Comment: A `ListView` is a better implementation. Think about what happens when you have many bits of text going back and forth. A `ListView` can recycle `View` objects and only keep enough in memory to display on screen. Other layouts will require you to potentially create lots of `View` objects leading to memory bloat.

Comment: Okay, in that case, how do I format the ListView to do what I want? Lol. We just went full circle here.